# jQuery validation for handlebars template with dynamic fields and array inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, handlebars.js

I have the following handlebars template :

```
<script id="hbar_task_config_holder" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <div class="row task_config_holder" id="task_config_each_holder">
        {{#tasks}}
        {{> config_row types=../types}}
        {{/tasks}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
        <button class="btn btn-purple btn-sm" id="add_task" >
            <i class="icon-plus bigger-110"></i>
            Add Task
        </button>
    </div>
</script>
```

This includes the following template partial :

```
<script id="config_row-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="row col-xs-12">
        <input type="hidden" id="task_id" value="{{id}}">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
            <input type="text" name="title[]" class="req col-xs-12" value="{{title}}" placeholder="Title" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
            <input type="text" class="req col-xs-12" name="url[]" value="{{url}}" placeholder="URL"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
            <input type="text" class="req col-xs-12" name="description[]" value="{{description}}" placeholder="Description"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
            <input type="text" class="req col-xs-6" name="amount[]" value="{{amount}}" placeholder="Amount"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Now I have a chosen select box and in the onchange, it will compile this whole template and append it to a div which is inside a form with ID `#task_form` and when I click on the `Add Task`, 
it is dynamically appending the input elements specifed in partial template. 
I am trying to add form validation to this using jQuery validator plugin. I tried a number of scenarios, but nothing seems working. I don't know whether this is a correct method for adding validation rules to dynamic elements, 
but I am now have the following code :

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#task_form').on('submit', function (event) {

        // prevent default submit action
        event.preventDefault();

        $("input.req").each (function (){
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).rules( "add", {
                required: true,
            });
        });

        // test if form is valid
        if($('#task_form').validate().form()) {
            console.log("validates");
        } else {
            console.log("does not validate");
        }

        $('#task_form').validate();
    });
});
```

This is throwing me an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
>       at init.rules (jquery.validate.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (:3:25)
>       at Function.each (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
>       at init.each (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
>       at :1:16

I have tried some other workarounds like adding the following code in the function, which is adding dynamic input elements.

```
$(#task_form).removeData('validator');
$(#task_form).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(#task_form);
```

But this is again throwing another error which is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
>       at :3:24

Sorry for the long post and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add fiddle?